# Drywall Type for Conditioned Basement

Tags: drywall, basement, moisture

In my conditioned basement, should mold and moisture resistant drywall be used? I've read varying accounts, including use it everywhere, use it on the walls (but not ceiling), use it on the bottom row on the walls only, or not at all.

The space is heated and cooled by the same central HVAC system as the above grade floors in the house. The basement used to have water issues, but we have had that fixed by professionals. Against the concrete block, foam board insulation has been installed between the block and framing, and then sealed with spray in foam.

Comment: It depends on your specific conditions. If there is very little chance of any dampness, there is no need. If there is a chance, then it is probably worth doing. In the overall scheme of things, the moisture resistant board is not all that expensive.

Comment: True. In our project, it'd roughly be $120-130 in material, so $150 or so after tax. Could be worth it for piece of mind.